# Oracle: get the closest date for each id efficiently

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a query that returns the closest (above) price for each id from table `price` for every date in table `date`.

`date` has these dates in it:

```
date
2010-11-25
2010-11-24
2010-11-10
```

`price` is as follows:

```
id  date        price
A   2010-11-26  24.99
A   2010-11-24  27.99
A   2010-11-13  22.12
B   2010-11-26  26.51
B   2010-11-24  23.24
B   2010-11-22  27.95
```

So for `2010-11-25` I should get

```
id  date        price
A   2010-11-26  24.99
B   2010-11-26  26.51
```

for `2010-11-10`

```
id  date        price
A   2010-11-13  22.12
B   2010-11-22  27.95
```

for `2010-11-24`

```
id  date        price
A   2010-11-24  27.99
B   2010-11-24  23.24
```

etc.

I believe getting the result for a given date is doable (maybe group by...having), however I am looking for a solution that does it for all the dates.

**EDIT:**

There was an error in the example, corrected...

Comment: I really can't see the logic in those 'B' records. Why should you get '2010-11-26' for '2010-10-25'?

Comment: @Golez Because that's the closest date for id `B` (I am guessing here)

Comment: I'd think so, if I read the explanation, but 2010-11-22 seems closer to me.

Comment: @Golez Indeed. It might be just an error.

Comment: I think so. And I based my answer on that assumption. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol  please see the **EDIT**, you were right:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this, but there may be an error in your example. (Or misunderstand it).

```
select
  id, date,price
from
  (select
    p.id,
    p.date,
    p.price,
    dense_rank() over (partition by d.date, p.id order by p.date) as rank
  from
    date d
    inner join price p on p.date > d.date)
where
  rank = 1
```

Comment: I think you are generating more rows than there should be

Comment: I think that may have been caused by `order by d.date` which should be `order by p.date`. Fixed this. Although I got to admit I don't have Oracle here and Notepad is a lousy query-tester. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    d.date AS searchDate
    p.id
    p.date
    p.price
FROM 
    date d
  ,                              --- this is a CROSS JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT id
      FROM price
    ) product
  JOIN
    price p
      ON  p.id = product.id
      AND p.date =
          ( SELECT MIN(p2.date)
            FROM price AS p2
            WHERE p2.date >= d.date
          )
```

Comment: @NullUserException: Can you try replacing `CROSS JOIN` with a comma `,` ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you, I think:

```
select x.date_1 as candidate_date ,
       t.*
from ( select d."date"        as date_1  ,
              p.id ,
              min( p."date" ) as date_2
        from      "date" d
        left join price  p on p."date" >= d."date"
        group by p.id     ,
                 d."date"
     ) x
left join price t on t.id     = x.id
                 and t."date" = x.date_2
order by 1,2,3
```

The virtual table in the from clause should give you 1 row for every "id" in the price table with a date greater than or equal to your candidate date from the date table.

Comment: I think you are also generating more rows than there should be